Finding the Laurent series for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+z}-e^{-z}$ on $A(-1,1, \infty)$

Find the Laurent series for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+z}-e^{-z}; |z+1|>1$

Firstly,
$$\frac{1}{z^2+z}=\frac{1}{z(z+1)}=\frac{1}{z+1}\frac{-1}{1-(z+1)}=\frac{1}{z+1}(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}(z+1)^n)$$
But for the other summand,
$$e^{-z}=e^{-(z+1)+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-(z+1)+1)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}(-1)^k(z+1)^k)}{n!}$$
But I cannot find a nice way to express this second term; any suggestions?

For all $z \in \Bbb C$ is
$$
 e^{-z} = e \cdot e^{-(z+1)} =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty e \frac{(-1)^n }{n!} (z+1)^n
$$
so this is the Taylor series of $e^z$ at $z_0 = -1$, and in particular the Laurent series of $e^z$ in any annulus with center $z_0 = -1$.
